# Add a scaled watermark to video thumbnails with FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images

I'm trying to capture images from a video every 60 seconds AND add a copyright watermark at the bottom of each image that is captured.  The below command captures and overlays, but the watermark doesn't seem to be scaled and/or positioned as expected.

As best as I can tell, it's scaling the captured image, but  *not* the watermark.  The confusion is that it happens to be a 640x480 video being scaled to 640x480, and the watermark is already 640x480, yet the output image has a "stretched" watermark.

- The input video dimensions may vary, but are always 4:3
- The output image must always be 640x480.
- The source watermark is 640x20
- I want it to appear on the very bottom of the image.

I've been experimenting with the `filter-complex`, but can't get a handle on the syntax to specify how to scale which input, and where to position things.  I'm quite new to FFMPEG, and am finding the documentation exhaustive, but confusing to a beginner.

What needs to be added or changed in this to get the output I'm looking for.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png  
-filter_complex "overlay=0:main_h-overlay_h,thumbnail, scale=640:480, fps=1/60"  
image"_%05d.jpg"
```

Any assistance is appreciated, and thanks in advance,

Comment: You need to show the complete console output from your command. The info will help with providing an answer.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I've actually figured out a way around it, so will be deleting the question, but thank you looking at it :)

Comment: Instead of deleting it you can provide answers to your own questions.